# Incorrect result with islower when using ctypes

Tags: python, c, ctypes

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> import ctypes.util
>>> libc = CDLL("libc.so.6")
>>> libc.printf("%c\n", 104)
h
2
>>> libc.islower(104) # Works fine
512
>>> libc.islower.restype = c_bool # But when i do this...
>>> libc.islower(104)
False
>>> c_bool(512)
c_bool(True)
```

personally, i think 'h' is lower case..

Is this a bug in ctypes, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: In C any nonzero value is true. So 512 is a fine indicator that h is lower case. Internally ctypes is usually implemented as a table of bitmaps one per char.  This one must use bit 9 for lower case.

Comment: @Gene I think he's asking about `False` on the last command.

Comment: oh indeed, but when i replace the return type with c_bool, it returns false

Comment: Probably c_bool is erroneously declared as a char so 2^9 coerced to c_bool loses the 1 bit.

Comment: Suggest dropping C tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`restype` is not there just to tell the Python output type, but, most importantly, to tell what is the C type to expect, and thus how to marshal it. `islower` returns an `int`, which is typically 4 bytes wide; if you say it returns a `bool` (which is normally 1 byte) you are breaking the expectations of the marshaling code.

This time you got an incorrect result (probably because on your platform the return code goes in a register, and so it's just taking the lower 8 bits of it), on another platform or for another type this could easily break the stack, and thus crash your process.

So: don't do that. Always respect the C API types and convert *after* the call.